# Intel MPI mpirun does not terminate using java Process.destroy()

Tags: java, mpi, intel-mpi

My Intel MPI version is impi/5.0.2.044/intel64 installed on a RHEL machine.

I am using java to invoke an MPI program using the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("mpirun ./myProgram");
builder.redirectError(Redirect.to(new File("stderr")));
builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(new File("stdout")));
Process p = null;
try {
    p = builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Process has started here
p.destroy();
try {
    // i = 143
    int i = p.exitValue();
} catch( IllegalThreadStateException e){
}
```

But even after the `exitValue()` is known without throwing exception, `ps aux` still shows a bunch of `./myProgram`, and the program is still writing result files as if it is not being killed, terminating only after it finishes all its calculation.

Currently, the only way I find successful to terminate `./myProgram` is to terminate the java using `Ctrl+C` in the console to the java program.

My intention is to stop the calculation immediately and let the java program schedule some other calculation. Is there any walkaround to force all mpi instances to terminate, or at least guarantee a termination in small, definite amount of time (e.g. 30s or 1 min of polling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the JDK implementation of `destroy` sends `SIGTERM`, which shuts down `mpirun` hard.
See [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/jdk7-b147/src/solaris/native/java/lang/UNIXProcess_md.c#l947) for the relevant JDK source.

You need to send `SIGINT` to give MPI a chance to shut down gracefully.

E.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 <pid>");`

You can get the PID by invoking `mpirun` with `--report-pid`. (read the man-page)

**edit**

You can alternatively use reflection to figure out the PID of a process you started under a UNIX-like OS (stolen from [here](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid)). As we are talking about kill and signal, that should not be a restriction.

```
if(process.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
  /* get the PID on unix/linux systems */
  try {
    Field f = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    pid = f.getInt(p);
  } catch (Throwable e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand what the problem is. I killed the MPI launcher but not the program. However, my version of `mpirun` does not respond to `--report-pid` option and also the `I_MPI_DEBUG` environmental variable, so I have no idea how to get the PID.

Comment: see the edit for a generic way to find the pid from java.

Comment: Thanks for the reflection code. I should accept your solution as it is generally the right one. But still the Intel MPI is too cursed not propagating my signal. I tried hangup(1), interrupt(2), kill(9) and terminate(15), either nothing being terminated, or having the daemon dead without terminating MPI processes.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe consider posting to the Intel dev forum, you might get better support there.